# capture popup feature attribute in pop action

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I've got an action function for my popup and I need to access the feature attributes from the pop up within the action function.  In the code below I'd like to access {SAWID} -- I dont see it in the event parameter sent to the function.

```
var ContactsAction = {
                title: "Get Contacts",
                id: "contacts-this",

            };

            var template = {
                // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "{Name}",
                content: "{SAWID}",
                actions: [ContactsAction]
            };

      // Event handler that fires each time an action is clicked.
            view.popup.on("trigger-action", lang.hitch(this, this.Contacts));

            // Executes when GetContacts is clicked in pop ups
        Contacts: function (event) {
            if (event.action.id === "contacts-this") {
                //grab SAWID
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Pete

Comment: What version of the API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works, although its probably not the best way to do it:

there is an innerText property on the even.target object that includes all the text in the pop up.  If I parse the innerText property I can get what I need:  If anyone knows of a cleaner way please let me know.  Thanks

```
       // Executes when GetContacts is clicked in pop ups
        Contacts: function (event) {
            if (event.action.id === "contacts-this") {
                var str = event.target.innerText;
                var start = str.indexOf("Close") + 6;//"Close" always precedes my SAWID
                var end = str.indexOf("Zoom") - 1;//"Zoom" is always after my SAWID
                var SAWID = str.substring(start, end);
                alert(SAWID);
            }
        }
```